# React with TS can't see any contect inside background wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the register component code -

```
const RegisterView = () => {
  return (
    <Background>
      <h1>ddd</h1>
    </Background>
  );
};
```

The background scss -

```
.mainContainer {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 80vh;
  min-width: 140vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  
  &:after {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 140px;
    right: 140px;
    bottom: 90px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

Background component view.tsx -

```
import classes from './Background.module.scss';

const BackgroundView = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes['mainContainer']}></div>
  );
};

BackgroundView.displayName = 'Background';
BackgroundView.defaultProps = {};

export default BackgroundView;
```

Background component tsx -

```
import BackgroundView from './Background.view';

const Background = () => {
  return (
    <BackgroundView />
  );
};

Background.displayName = 'Background';
Background.defaultProps = {};

export default Background;
```

The `Background` component should be a wrapper for all other components. Here is what I'm getting right now -

[image]

I can't get any content inside the component, what is the problem?

Comment: you are not using the `children` prop

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski new to react, how can i use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wrapped `BackgroundView` in a `Background` component you've written like this:

```
const Background = () => {
  return (
    <BackgroundView />
  );
};
```

That throws away any children you've provided to the `Background` component. If you want to put those children in the `BackgroundView`, you have to do that explicitly:

```
const Background = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <BackgroundView>{children}</BackgroundView>
  );
};
```

You have the same problem with `BackgroundView`, so:

```
const BackgroundView = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes['mainContainer']}>{children}</div>
  );
};
```

It's also not clear why you have `Background` at all. You could just use `BackgroundView` directly.

---

Just as a side note, there's no need for the `()` around JSX elements (provided you start the JSX element on the line with the `return`, **not** the next line):

```
const Background = ({children}) => {
  return <BackgroundView>{children}</BackgroundView>;
};
```

and in fact, if you like, you can use the concise form of the arrow function:

```
const Background = ({children}) => <BackgroundView>{children}</BackgroundView>;
```

but those are both just style things, you may prefer to do it differently.